# Why are pip packages not installed to $PATH to by default?

Tags: python, path, pip, environment, package-managers

Typically when using `rubygems` in the `ruby` ecosystem or `npm`/`yarn` in the JavaScript ecosystem packages are installed somewhere on the `$PATH` or at least you are instructed to add the package install location to your path `$PATH`.

It seems like with `pip` in the `python` ecosystem there is never an emphasis on this. Instead, you are encouraged to run modules via `python -m <name>`, etc.

Seems a bit odd to me, was this just a design decision? Is it good practice to put `site-packages` or whatever location `pip` is using into `$PATH`? Sometimes a binary is added to `/usr/local/bin` (and sometimes with a different name than the package itself e.g `django-admin` instead of `django` with `pip install Django` whereas the binary is usually the same as the package name in `ruby`/JavaScript ecosystems), for example, I see, but is that all of the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing `$PATH` and `$PYTHONPATH`. `site-packages` is for **libraries**,  `$PATH` is for **programs** (binaries and scripts). `pip` installs libraries into its `site-packages` and scripts to the corresponding `bin/` directory; e.g. if `site-packages` is `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` scripts are installed into `/usr/local/bin/`.

`pip` doesn't check if `/usr/local/bin/`is in `$PATH`. Well, I agree with you — it should check and remind user to add `bin/` directory to `$PATH` if it's not already there.

Comment: "it should check and remind user to add bin/ directory to $PATH if it's not already there." - well, that is the same directory where your `python` executable is located, so if it is not in $path then your directory structure is very weird. I don't think pip (in fact, distutils) should check this

Comment: *that is the same directory where your python executable is located* — not necessary: I can run `/usr/local/bin/pip install` and `pip` script has `#!/usr/local/bin/python` shebang so `/usr/local/bin/` could be absent from the `$PATH`.

Comment: @phd how does pip know how to place binaries in `/bin` and the rest of the packages and modules in `/site-packages/`? So for instance if I create a python package, add it to PyPi and it has one entry point, like a binary, which would import the rest of the modules and do some stuff when fed with a file... like `flake8` for instance.. you do `flake8 filename` which is an executable. How does pip know to place that `flake8` in bin and the rest of the `packages` and `modules` in `/site-packages/`? or if you could point me in the direction where I could read about this, ty in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

The `site-packages` directory for a particular python installation is automatically added to `sys.path` when you run the binary for the installation.  When that binary executes `import modname`, it looks in the directories on sys.path.  So when you run `pip install` with a particular python binary, `pip`, by default, puts the package in the `site-packages` for that binary so that binary can import the package.  Advanced used can do more complicated things.